# Azure Cosmos SQL API - How do I store a custom object as @PartitionKey

Tags: java, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-java-sdk

Is it possible to store a custom POJO as a Json String using @PartitionKey using Java 8.? Is yes, please tell me how .

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.PartitionKey;

    @PartitionKey
        private Result result;
```

result will have value like `{"resultID":"1","secret":"my secret"}`

Comment: You can have nested path configured

Comment: could you please elaborate on your that ? code snippets will be of help

Comment: It is not possible to specify an object as your partition key in Cosmos DB. There is work however to provide sub-partitioning for the Core (SQL) API that allows you to specify up to 3 properties that act as a hierarchy for your partitions. If you are interested, there is a private preview of this. Sign up is here. https://aka.ms/cosmos-subpartitioning-signup

Comment: @MarkBrown, thanks ! here's  how I solved it for now (my ans. below) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As rightly commented by @Mark Brown, I figured that - "It is not possible to specify an object as your partition key in Cosmos DB" , however I did a nested partition key path , like so:

```
import com.azure.spring.data.cosmos.core.mapping.Container;

    @Container(containerName = "DcLogins", partitionKeyPath = "/result/company",autoScale = true)
    public class DcLogins {
     private Result result;
 
    public class Result {
     private String company;
```

Just to mention, in the `partitionKeyPath`, the  `result` is object of  `Result` and `company` variable in should match the json object your dealing with `{"company":"sapcustid","secret":"my secret"}`